# Не получается поставить node.js версии 6.1.0 на Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, ppa

Я новичок в **Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial)**, пока всё делаю на уровне обезьянки: нашёл инструкцию-сделал.
Нужна самая новая версия **node.js (6.1.0)**. apt-get'ом ставится 4.4.

Ни один способ: ppa, ppa руками, установить прекомпилированную версию с сайта, скачанную обычным способом - не получается осуществить. Перерыл все мыслимые руководства, только запутался. При любых, рабочих у других людей, вариантах возникают ошибки.

При попытке установить скачанную с [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/) последнюю версию - постоянно не находит `./configure`.

Когда с помощью **ppa** пытался установить или просто проапгрейдить - выдаёт:

```
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Может ли кто-нибудь дать внятный способ и помочь разобраться с ошибками, если они возникнут. Предоставлю скрины и другую нужную информацию.

Comment: А ручками собирать из исходников пробовали? node.js отлично собирается даже на экзотических платформах вроде armv6

Comment: @DmitriySimushev "собрать из исходников" - это и есть, судя по всему (я новичок), вариант по типу

"wget -N http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz
tar xzvf node-latest.tar.gz && cd node-v*
./configure"

В таком варианте у меня каждый раз не находит файл ./configure, не понимаю, как.

Comment: `ls -l | grep "node"` что выдает?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Ничего

Comment: Эм... а вы архив то распаковываете? И он реально распаковывается? Файлы появляются?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev
Вот, в распакованном архиве вбил. Так?
В этой же папке пытался по инструкции делать ./configure, make install и др, но никакого ./configure не находит
https://pp.vk.me/c630718/v630718722/3c844/qot54DZCgYM.jpg

Comment: Судя по скриншоту, архив мягко говоря не полный. попробуйте скачать его еще раз и повторно распаковать. И да, в архиве  http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz файл `configure` есть. Я проверил

Answer (score 1):

Помимо apt-get install есть еще варинты:

Попробуйте этот

Используя NVM:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev
curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh -o install_nvm.sh
nano install_nvm.sh
bash install_nvm.sh
source ~/.profile
nvm ls-remote
nvm install 6.1.0
nvm use 6.1.0
node -v
```

// должно вывести 6.1.0 в терминал.

Либо еще раз через PPA, но с команды в такой послежовательности:
Используя PPA:

```
cd ~
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
nano nodesource_setup.sh
sudo bash node_setup.sh
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Вот хороший туториал по Вашей проблеме:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо.

В итоге решил проблему (по совету друга) так:

В файле

> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

```
sudo rm jerome*
```

Удалил этот пакет, т.к. именно старый пакет мешал установиться новым, выбивая ошибку.

После этого способ через

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodej
```

благополучно заработал.